# Drag drop text in Delphi

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop

Background: Still trying to bring a D2007 project up to D10.1...

For drag and drop of text from/to Word, Outlook, etc, I was using Melanders drag drop suite ( http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop ) which was awesome, but after several hours trying to get it to compile under 10.1 Berlin I have given up.

Does anyone have example/demo/component to drag text from/to a Delphi control?

Alternatively has anyone successfully patched Melanders drag drop suite?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [DelphiPraxis](https://github.com/DelphiPraxis/The-Drag-and-Drop-Component-Suite-for-Delphi) repository which contains and updated version of the component.

Comment: Thanks, Melanders should really link to this

Answer (score 2):

You can get it from the [DelphiPraxys github right here](https://github.com/DelphiPraxis/The-Drag-and-Drop-Component-Suite-for-Delphi) its based on Melanders and already supported by Delphi 10.1 Berlin.